# Using a GPU with Tensorflow Eager Execution on Google Colaboratory

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to offload computing to a GPU in Tensorflow eager execution on Google Colaboratory, but due to the way Colab handles GPUs I'm having trouble.

Normally, when using a GPU you change the runtime to a GPU accelerated one and Tensorflow automatically uses the available GPU for your calculations. If you were to try and set the GPU manually, you'd find you can't because there isn't one in the list of connected devices.

Eager execution, however, doesn't automatically use a GPU if one is available, and because you can't set one manually it doesn't seem like one can be used.

Please see the attached notebook: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NeJQoO5Yi5V-m7Hmm85wmm1Cl5SrY33m/view?usp=sharing

Trying to specify a GPU to use throws the following error: `RuntimeError: Error copying tensor to device: /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0. /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 unknown device.`

Answer (score -1):

Eager execution does in fact let you specify GPUs manually (for example, search for "GPU" in https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/eager).

The particular error message you've included indicates that TensorFlow can't find a GPU, so make sure that you've installed the GPU-compatible version of TensorFlow 1.7. After you've done that, you'll need to make one more change to your code. In particular, copy the tensors `x` and `y` to GPU before multiplying them, like so:

```
with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
     x = x.gpu()
     y = y.gpu()
     %timeit x * y
```

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I wasn't clear in the question. I'm aware of how to set a gpu device (as you can see in the notebook), but devices on Google Colaboratory aren't detected (so they can only be used automatically and not set manually).

Comment: Ah interesting. You're right --- this seems to be a bug in Google's Colaboratory. Even the sample [GPU notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/gpu.ipynb)  fails to detect a GPU. The [FAQs page](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html) has instructions for reporting bugs.